# SyntaxError: multiple statements found in python. Does anyone have experience with this?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The following code is from the textbook in our intro to python class. Between asking my classmates, the instructor, and searching this problem on the internet, no one seems to understand where the error is coming from. My instructor said he couldn't see where a second statement was coming from. If anyone has any experience with this or any suggestions I would greatly appreciate it.

```
>>> # quadratic.py
#   A program that computes the real roots of a quadratic equation.
#   Note: this program crashes if the equation has no real roots.

import math  # Makes the math library available.

def main():
    print("This program finds the real solutions to a quadratic")
    print()

    a,b,c = eval(input("Please enter the coefficients (a,b,c): "))

    discRoot = math.sqrt(b*b*-4*a*c)
    root1 = (b + discRoot) / (2 * a)
    root2 = (b - discRoot) / (2 * a)

    print()
    print("The solutions are: ", root1, root2)

main()
SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've pasted a whole script into an interactive shell in some IDE. Your IDE isn't passing along the lines one by one to Python, but all at once. The code underlying the interactive shell doesn't like this, so you're getting an error.

I'd suggest putting your code into a file and then running it, rather than entering the code via the shell directly. If  you really need to only use the interactive shell, separate out the different statements onto their own input lines (the `import` statement at the top, the `def` statement in the middle, and the `main()` expression statement at the end).

Comment: That was my guess, too, and it really looks like he did, but I can not reproduce that error message this way.

Comment: @tobias_k: I get exactly that error message pasting mutli-line code into IDLE's shell, so I suspect that's what the questioner is doing.

Comment: Ok so running it from a file made some progress, but now I am getting a different error.

This program finds the real solutions to a quadratic
()
Please enter the coefficients (a,b,c): 1,2,3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/elkyfrostglen/Desktop/quadratic.py", line 20, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/elkyfrostglen/Desktop/quadratic.py", line 11, in main
    a,b,c = eval(input("Please enter the coefficients (a,b,c): "))
TypeError: eval() arg 1 must be a string or code object

Comment: @elkyfrostglen Then maybe you are using Python 2.7 instead of Python 3? In Python 2, `input` will already evaluate the input, so you are evaluating twice. Iin Python 3, `input` will just return a string, like `raw_input` does in Python 3. Also, try not to use `eval`.

Comment: Still can't reproduce, neither with `python`, nor `ipython`, nor `idle`, with neither Python 2 nor 3. But this seems to solve (part of) OP's problem so I guess the guess was right after all.

Comment: I get the same error message in IDLE from Python 3.5. Make sure you're not copying the `>>>` prompt on the first line and that you haven't copied any extra indentation (the original code in the question before I edited it has an extra four spaces).